# Stop destroying network performance every time an app scans for wifi networks

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, high-sierra

While trying to debug poor video chat quality, I noticed that certain apps cause periodic ping latency spikes even while pinging my router.

I tracked the problem down to the fact that the apps (e.g. Genymotion, qbittorrent) seem to be scanning for wifi networks every few seconds. (When I turned on debug wifi logging, I kept seeing lines like `Info: <airportd[74491]> SCAN request received from pid 76811 (genymotion) with priority 0` that correlated with the latency spikes.)

Is there any way for me to stop this from happening? It basically means I can't run Genymotion and have a video call at the same time because it'll stutter every 10-15 seconds.

Comment: Did you try monitoring the airportd process (its memory)? Maybe restart the computer or kill airportd?

Comment: The problem happens whenever airportd scans for new networks--turns out the "misbehaving" apps were polling for open wifi networks every few seconds (I just edited the question based on this). But I don't see anything useful in the activity monitor; airportd is hovering around 20.6mb used. The problem persists across restarts too.

Comment: I'm glad my intuition about airportd was right :)

I did a bit of googling, and it seems [somebody experienced the same problem with qbittorrent](https://redd.it/77bxiz).
It seems to come from Qt.

Comment: The ticket already exists on the Qt tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34641?focusedCommentId=354587&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-354587

Comment: I found https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14816448. Could you try to "Set the QT_BEARER_POLL_TIMEOUT environment variable to -1"?

 
It seems to be a well known problem: the solution for window is described [here](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/4209) as well but the code on [this article](https://lostdomain.org/2017/06/17/qt-qnetworkaccessmanager-causing-latency-spikes-on-wifi/) makes me think it will work on OSX too :)

Comment: Wow, that totally eluded my Google skills, thanks! Unfortunately that solution doesn't work for at least my Genymotion install. Maybe Genymotion is including an older version of Qt? If so, I guess there's probably no hope except for me to bug them to update or bug Qt to fix this awful problem

Comment: Yep, looked at the app bundle; it's using 5.4.2.

Comment: OK, Genymotion support gave me a fix for their application bundle: `rm /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/{,MacOS/player.app/Contents}/PlugIns/bearer/libq{corewlan,generic}bearer.dylib`. @Labo if you post an actual answer I'll award you the bounty for tracking it down to the Qt bug!

Comment: Interesting about Genymotion, I couldn't find their source. Thanks, I'm writing an answer right now! And for the record, I found your question because a friend of mine tagged me on your Facebook post ;)

Comment: i found location services also trigger wifi scans. Preferences→ Security & Privacy → Location Services → Enable Location Services = Off

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why this happens

It comes from the GUI library [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) that is used in both programs. Several people experienced the same thing and report it:

- [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/qBittorrent/comments/77bxiz/uhoh_qbt_is_bugged/)
- [bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34641?focusedCommentId=354587&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-354587) (the official bug tracker)

## How to solve it for the newest versions of Qt

Set the environment variable `QT_BEARER_POLL_TIMEOUT` to -1.

```
QT_BEARER_POLL_TIMEOUT=-1 open -a qbittorrent
```

The problem also happens on Windows, it is solved similarly:

```
set QT_BEARER_POLL_TIMEOUT=-1
qbittorrent.exe
```

**References:**

- [news.ycombinator.com](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14816448)
- [github.com](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/4209)
- [lostdomain.org](https://lostdomain.org/2017/06/17/qt-qnetworkaccessmanager-causing-latency-spikes-on-wifi/)

## How to solve it for Genymotion

Genymotion currently uses of Qt version 5.4.2 that doesn't support `QT_BEARER_POLL_TIMEOUT`.

@Ben Kuhn contacted the support and the solution is to launch this command:

```
rm /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/{,MacOS/player.app/Con‌​tents}/PlugIns/beare‌​r/libq{corewlan,gene‌​ric}bearer.dylib
```